# How to check linux-util package version?

Tags: package-management

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.4

I want to know which version of linux-util it is using.

Any method to check it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question is too easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you’re asking about `util-linux`,

```
dpkg -l util-linux
```

will tell you what version is installed.